# Select Data from multiple row for dashboard

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-visualization

I wanted to create a dashboard which fetches data from spreadsheet and generates the pie chart. I found this useful link https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#skeleton but it uses two columns for pie chart. I wanted to use 4 columns for my charts and generate pie charts based on each row rather than based on columns.
For example -  This selects columns Name and Donuts eaten from the sheet and creates the pie chart.

[image: Example 1]

and creates this [image]

What I want is to use the multiple columns to generate a pie chart. For example pie char for the person named Michael (pie chart with Donuts eaten, Cake eaten, Chocolates eaten)

Comment: The question is too broad. Have you already read https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets?

Comment: Yes. My question is how can I use multiple column data for pie chart.         
'view': {'columns': [0,3]}
This allows me to select column 0 and 3 but what if want to take more column than that??

Comment: the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format) for the `PieChart` only allows for two columns of data, it will ignore additional columns. you will need to transform the columns to rows before drawing the chart. it would be easier to provide an example, if you could share the code that builds the current dashboard...

Comment: @WhiteHat I followed this tutorial where you can see the code https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/07/19/converting-from-uiapp-chart-service-to-html-service-google-visualization-api/